# How to store code snippets in Strapi so I can consume them in SSG NextJS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, strapi

I'm pretty sure this might not be the usual case but please, hear me out; I'm using Strapi, and I'm creating some components and collections, one of those collections is required to have code snippets (specifically typescript), I have access to all of those snippets from a GitHub repository; I tried storing those snippets as strings, however, I can't parse that string in my NextJS App because cross scripting; Please bear with me, it's my first NextJS and Strapi project.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for with Strapi/NextJS? Any tips and/or advises are really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use JSON data format, so you can parse it in a more simple way, here the [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/content-type-builder/configuring-fields-content-type#-json).